How to fix 'Type is not assignable error' in Tyescript for an array of elements?
Been trying to get this to work but getting same error, relatively new to Typescript so an explanation of what this error means would be helpful:
const itemsRef = useRef<Array<HTMLLIElement | null>>([]);

...

<li
  ref={(el) => (itemsRef.current[index] = el)}
/li>


Error is as follows:
Type '(el: HTMLLIElement | null) => HTMLLIElement | null' is not assignable to type 'LegacyRef<HTMLLIElement> | undefined'.
  Type '(el: HTMLLIElement | null) => HTMLLIElement | null' is not assignable to type '(instance: HTMLLIElement | null) => void | (() => VoidOrUndefinedOnly)'.
    Type 'HTMLLIElement | null' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => VoidOrUndefinedOnly)'.
      Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'void | (() => VoidOrUndefinedOnly)'.


The error message you're seeing is essentially saying that the function you're providing to the ref prop is not of the correct type. React expects a ref to be either a function that returns void or a RefObject, but your function returns HTMLLIElement | null, which is not compatible.
You have to adjust your approach to use a callback ref instead of directly assigning to the array.
import React, { useRef, useEffect } from 'react';

function YourComponent() {
 const itemsRef = useRef<Array<HTMLLIElement | null>>([]);

 useEffect(() => {
    // Ensure itemsRef.current is initialized
    if (!itemsRef.current) {
      itemsRef.current = [];
    }
 }, []);

 const setRef = (el: HTMLLIElement | null, index: number) => {
    if (!itemsRef.current) {
      itemsRef.current = [];
    }
    itemsRef.current[index] = el;
 };

 return (
    <ul>
      {/* Example usage */}
      {Array.from({ length: 5 }).map((_, index) => (
        <li key={index} ref={(el) => setRef(el, index)}>
          Item {index + 1}
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
 );
}


Amazing, thank you so much. Managed to solve it by making sure it was initialized in the function.
